# How to enable text highlighting on a page using gquery gestures plugin?

Tags: java, gwt, gesture, gwtquery, gquery

I have a complex GWT application that is designed for mobile and has this [gwtquery-gestures-plugin](https://github.com/manolo/gwtquery-gesture-plugin) code in its (root) ApplicationPresenter:

```
$(RootPanel.get())
            .as(Gesture.Gesture)
            .on("tap", new Function()
            {
                @Override
                public boolean f(Event e)
                {
                    Log.info("tap:" + e.getType() + ", x:" + e.getClientX() + ", y:" + e.getClientY());

                    // handle tap events here

                    return true;
                }
            })
            .on("swipeone", new Function()
            {
                @Override
                public boolean f(Event e)
                {
                    GestureObjects.Options o = arguments(0);
                    int delta = (int) o.delta().get(0).moved();

                    Log.info(o.description() + ":" + o.directionName() + ", x:" + e.getClientX() + ", y:" + e.getClientY() + ", delta:" + delta);

                    // handle swipe events here

                    return true;
                }

            });
```

Unfortunately this plugin seems to totally hijack the native selection of text, so **the user can't copy and paste anything**. Is there a way to enable this, or a workaround of some kind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On closer inspection of the documentation, I found this static boolean `hasGestures` that can be used to check if we are loading on a mobile decive or not.

So the snippet now becomes:

```
if(Gesture.hasGestures) // only load for mobile devices
    {
        $(RootPanel.get())
                .as(Gesture.Gesture)
                .on("tap", new Function() 
                {
                    @Override
                    public boolean f(Event e)
                    {
                        Log.info("tap:" + e.getType() + ", x:" + e.getClientX() + ", y:" + e.getClientY());

                        return true;
                    }
                })
                .on("swipeone", new Function()
                {
                    @Override
                    public boolean f(Event e)
                    {
                        GestureObjects.Options o = arguments(0);
                        int delta = (int) o.delta().get(0).moved();

                        Log.info(o.description() + ":" + o.directionName() + ", x:" + e.getClientX() + ", y:" + e.getClientY() + ", delta:" + delta);

                        return true;
                    }

                });
    }
    else
    {
        Log.info("Not adding gesture handlers as this is not a mobile device!");
    }
```